# How do I make text appear letter by letter in a box in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

So I need a way to make a text box with text that appears letter by letter (like ones you see in Undertale, Earthbound, and many more RPGs). I was wondering how I could do that in Pygame (I dont have code I just need help with how I would be able to do this)

Comment: can you please put an image or text, on how you want the text to appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Typewriter Effect Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101662/typewriter-effect-pygame). The basic idea is that you use a timer event ([`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer)) and append the text letter by letter:

```py
typewriter_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(typewriter_event, 100)

text = 'Hello World'
typewriter_text = ""

while run:
    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == typewriter_event:
            if len(typewriter_text) < len(text):
                typewriter_text += text[len(typewriter_text)]
```

Unfortunately pygame cannot render text with line breaks. You have to render the test line by line. See [Rendering text with multiple lines in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014195/rendering-text-with-multiple-lines-in-pygame)